# if $x$ and $y$ are commuting and have coprime orders then $\langle x,y\rangle $ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, let $x,u \in G$ show that if $x$ and $y$ commute and have coprime orders then $\langle x,y\rangle$ is cyclic.

Knowing that $$\langle x,y\rangle= \{u_1 u_2, \ldots, u_k: u_i \in \{x,x^{-1}, y,y^{-1}\}\}$$  any element of $\langle x,y\rangle $ can be written as product of $x$s and $y$s powers (i.e $w\in\langle x,y\rangle $ then $w=x^n y^m$ for some natural numbers $n,m$)

Any ideas?

I tried to show that the group is generated by $w=x^n y^m$ but I couldn't reach to anything,

Comment: Not quite, the group is generated by $xy$. Notice that $<x,y>$ has $\alpha\beta$ elements, where $\alpha$ is the order of $x$ and $\beta$ is the order of $y$, the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are coprime allows you to show that $(xy)^m$ covers all $\alpha\beta$ elements of the group.

Comment: By Lagrange's Theorem applied to $\langle x\rangle \cap\langle y\rangle$ in $G$, $\langle x\rangle \cap\langle y\rangle=\{e\}$. Then, since $xy=yx$, we have that $$\begin{align}\langle x,y\rangle &\cong \langle x^s,y^t, xy=yx\rangle\\ &\cong \Bbb Z_s\times\Bbb Z_t\\ &\cong \Bbb Z_{st},\end{align}$$ where the last isomorphism is given by the Chinese remainder theorem since the order $s,t$ are coprime.

Comment: @Marcos can I say in general the order of $<x,y>$ is the order of $x$ multiplied by the order of $y$?

Comment: If $x,y$ does not commute it is not true (why?), if $x,y$ commute then $<x,y>$ is always $\mathbb{Z}_\alpha\times\mathbb{Z}_\beta$ so yes, the order is $\alpha\beta$ .

Comment: @Marcos of course if they commute if they not we can't write the elements as power of $x$ and $y$

Comment: Well actually, to be more precise, it might happen that $x$ and $y$ does not commute but the order is the product, the dihedral group is an example. But in general we cant say anything.